# What is the difference between click() and tap() method in appium while writing test cases

Tags: appium, python-appium

Suppose I have to tap on a menu navigation button. I have tried `click()` and `tap()` both are working fine but which one is preferred(for both emulator and physical device)

Comment: A li'l description about these : https://discuss.appium.io/t/difference-between-click-and-tap/295/2

Answer (score 1):

tap() method belongs to AppiumDriver class while the click() method belongs to the WebDriver class

I think, it is better to use driver.tap() method as it is more closely binded to the mobile scenario. and we can use on both emulator and real device.  the result is same

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that click is for computers and tap for touch screen/mobile devices (phone, tablette)